# Split number into two parts in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I split below number into two parts,

```
112345678
```

Result should be an array,

```
['11', '2345678']
```

So far I tried,

```
function (number, end) {
   console.log(number.slice(0, end));
}
```

This returns,

```
 11
```

Comment: On what rule did you split the string into '11' & '2345678'?

Comment: Can use substring

Comment: @Addis rule is 2:infinity, I need first 2 digits and all others result should be two elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply make a custom function which takes in the num and the position from where you want to split:

```js
function splitNum(num, pos){
 num = num.toString();
 return [num.substring(0, pos), num.substring(pos)];
}

let num = 112345678;

console.log(splitNum(num,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is write a simple function using substring in javascript.

```js
var charvalue = "112345678";
function FunctiontoSplitnumber(charvalue, position) {
  var firstpart = charvalue.substring(0, position);
  var secondpart = charvalue.substring(position, charvalue.length);
}

console.log(FunctiontoSplitnumber(charvalue,2))
```